# String from not fully filled character array

Tags: java, string, arrays

The following code, obviously, gives a rather weird result.

```
char[] data = new char[5];
data[0] = 'a';
data[1] = 'b';
data[2] = 'c';

out.println("'" + new String(data) + "'");
```

> 'abc□□'

Is there a way to create a string from a character array which takes into account that the whole array might not be filled to the end with characters?

---

**Reason for question:** When using the [`Reader.read(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5b%5d%29) method you give it a character array to fill, which I can only assume won't be fully filled, unless you're lucky, when you reach the end of the stream. So was wondering how you could turn this into a string you could append to a `StringBuffer`. Realize now though that the `read` method actually returns the number of bytes read though, which I assume can be used in combination with `StringBuffer.append(char[], int, int)`, which renders my question moot. But, still something I am curious about and not something I managed to find by googling, so I guess this question is good to have an answer for here ;)

Comment: Is it the case that the solution must cope with embedded null characters and if so, what should the behavior be?

Comment: If by embedded you mean mixed in with the other characters, then no.

Comment: The real question here is how did the null chars get there in the first place? Are you ignoring a read result count further back?

Comment: @EJP Honestly I didn't think of the read result until after I posted this question so the question is kind of moot for my particular case now, but still curious if there are any smart solutions for when you don't have that count :)

Comment: Reader.read(char[]) returns how many characters were read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` has constructor[String(char[] value, int offset, int count)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) that accepts an array of `char` plus length (and offset):

```
String s = new String(data, 0, 3);
```

Assuming no embedded null characters (where a leading null character is considered to be an embedded null) in `data` the solution would need to locate the first null character to determine the number of `char` in `data`:

```
int length = 0;
while (length < data.length && 0 != data[length]) length++;
String s = new String(data, 0, length);
```

Comment: Assumes the OP knows in advance which chars are missing.

Comment: @Baz, what do you mean by _edge_ ?

Comment: @hmjd Sorry, I meant `ab□c□` for example. In this case your method won't eliminate the first missing char.

Comment: @Baz, and what should the `String` look like in that case? Should the missing `char` be purged, replace with a space? Is this actually a requirement?

Comment: @hmjd Don't ask me, ask the OP. The OP just said: "_that the whole array might not be filled_".

Comment: @Baz - I would assume that `data` is a buffer that you fill with characters starting from index zero, and incrementing the index.  That is how buffers *normally* work.  And that is what "fill" implies to me.  In fact, since it is not possible to distinguish the contents of an array element that has been written to from that one that has not been written to, it is hard to see how any other interpretation makes sense.  (Note that `0x0000` is a valid character!)

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I agree. I just wanted to point out, that the question is ambiguous. The OP did clarify this in the meantime.

Comment: I clarified that it was the end that might not be filled. Not random places in the array. Sorry about the ambiguity :)

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted since it covers both cases (known and unknown length) and also doesn't use any StringBuilders or anything. Nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a robust method that doesn't work as follows:

```
char[] data = new char[5];
data[0] = 'a';
data[1] = 'b';
data[2] = 'c';

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : data) {
  if (c != 0x00) {
    builder.append(c);
  }
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

This specifically omits characters with a value equal to the default (`0x00`). Note, this is far from perfect as `0x00` is a legitimate char. I would suggest you re-evaluate the design decisions that lead you to this point.

I'm not a fan of the solutions that assume `((char) 0x00)` is whitespace and can be trimmed. Even if it works. Note that:

```
System.out.println(' ' == ((char) 0x00));
```

will print `false`.

Comment: Is `0x00` different from just `0`?

Comment: @DuncanJones - It should be noted that the OP has clarified his question to make it clear that 1) the invalid characters are always at the end, and 2) he knows the position of the last valid character.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is use string [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) with offset and length.

```
 String(char[] value, int offset, int count) 

 new String(data,0,3)
```

Now if exact value is not known then you can write utility method to correct the array. Or use `trim()` to trim trailing characters.

```
 public static char[] getNotMessedUpArray(char[] messedUp) {

    int messedUpIndex = messedUp.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < messedUp.length; i++) {
        if (messedUp[i] <= ' ') {
            System.arraycopy(messedUp, i + 1, messedUp, i, messedUp.length
                    - i - 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < messedUp.length; i++) {
        if (messedUp[i] <= ' ') {
            messedUpIndex--;
        }
    }
    char[] notMessedUp = new char[messedUpIndex];
    System.arraycopy(messedUp, 0, notMessedUp, 0, messedUpIndex);
    return notMessedUp;

}
```

Comment: Then you'd have to know exactly how many have been set though.

Comment: Then you will have to iterate over string and check that each character is `<= ' '//Space char` and create new string.